# Dropdown Select Box not showing correctly with custom CSS?

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, safari, webkit

How can I add custom CSS select box styling for Chrome and Safari? IS there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
You need to add -webkit-appearance: none; and a height value for Chrome and Safari.

Any Suggestions?

Resource: 
http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Try it on JSFiddle Remove and add that style in Google Chrome:

**Before:**
 - http://jsfiddle.net/JoshSalway/jw6Qy/

**After:**
 - http://jsfiddle.net/JoshSalway/cMbTB/

```
select{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Did you post your question *before* googling it?

Comment: @metadept Actually I found it on Google thanks for the comment. Actually adding the question to help developers you wang.

Answer (score 0):

**<select> tags are stubborn creatures but there *is* a way.**

If there's a "size" parameter in the tag, almost any CSS will apply. Using this technique, I've created a fiddle that's practically equivalent to a normal select tag, plus the value can be edited manually like a ComboBox in visual languages (unless you put *readonly* in the input tag).

So here's a minimal example to see the principle behind:
*(you'll need jQuery for the clicking mechanism)*:

```
<style>

    /* only these 2 lines are truly required */
    .stylish span {position:relative;}
    .stylish select {position:absolute;left:0px;display:none}

    /* now you can style the hell out of them */
    .stylish input    { ... }
    .stylish select   { ... }
    .stylish option   { ... }
    .stylish optgroup { ... }

</style>
...
<div class="stylish">
    <label> Choose your superhero: </label>
    <span>
        <input onclick="$(this).closest('div').find('select').slideToggle(110)">
        <br>
        <select size=15 onclick="$(this).hide().closest('div').find('input').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());">

            <optgroup label="Fantasy"></optgroup>
            <option value="gandalf">Gandalf</option>
            <option value="harry">Harry Potter</option>
            <option value="jon">Jon Snow</option>

            <optgroup label="Comics"></optgroup>
            <option value="tony">Tony Stark</option>
            <option value="steve">Steven Rogers</option>
            <option value="natasha">Natasha Romanova</option>

        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle with some more styles:
https://jsfiddle.net/dkellner/7ac9us70/

Hope this helps!